# jQuery with radio button

Tags: jquery

What's wrong with this code? Why doesn't it show value?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#radio_div').change(function(event){
            var value = $("input[@name='rdio']:checked").val();
            $('#update_text').html('Radio value:' + value);
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>                                                                 
    <body>  

    <div id="radio_div">
        <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="a" />
        <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="b" />
        <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="c" />
    </div>
    <div id="update_text">Please push radio button</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're binding to the change event of the radio_div div.  A div does not fire a change event, only input elements do that..

Do this instead:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#radio_div input').change(function(event){
        var value = $("input[@name='rdio']:checked").val();
        $('#update_text').html('Radio value:' + value);
    });
});
</script>
</head>                                                                 
<body>  

<div id="radio_div">
    <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="a" />
    <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="b" />
    <input type="radio" name="rdio" value="c" />
</div>
<div id="update_text">Please push radio button</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're adding a `change` handler to a `<div>` element.
Since `<div>` elements never generate `change` events, your code doesn't work.

Instead, you should add the `change` handler to the `input` elements *inside* the `<div>` element, like this:

```
$('#radio_div :radio').change(...)
```

(The [`:radio` selector](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) matches radio inputs)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('#radio_div input:radio').click(function() { 
    if($(this).is(':checked'))  {
        $(this).val(); // $(this).attr('value'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#radio_div input[@name='rdio']").change(function(event){
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $('#update_text').html('Radio value:' + value);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you put event handler on change for div, and there is nothing changes there. You need to do:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[@name='rdio']").click(function(event){
        if ( $(this).checked)
           console.log( $(this).value);
    });
});
```